# Passing class objects to another class method Python

Tags: python, class, object

I am trying to understand where my mistake lies and I was hoping you could please help me.

I have this code:

```
import copy
class FooInd():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1

class Planning():
    def foo(self,pop):
        print(pop.a)

    def main():
        ind=FooInd()
        Planning.foo(copy.deepcopy(ind))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Planning.main()
```

However I keep receiving this error:

```
Planning.foo(copy.deepcopy(ind))
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pop'
```

I believe that the mistake is not in the foo method definition, but in my class initiation of the FooInd, however I have checked the Python documentation for classes and I could not find a solution.

Does anyone have a clue of what could I try or where can I check?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: ``Planning.foo`` takes one parameter *in addition to the ``Planning`` instance ``self``*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `Planning.foo` on the class, not an instance of the class. You provided the *second* argument it requires, but not the `self` argument.

You have two choices:

1. Construct a `Planning` instance to call `foo` on:

   ```
   def main():
       ind=FooInd()
       Planning().foo(copy.deepcopy(ind))
       #       ^^ Makes simple instance to call on
   ```
2. Make `foo` a `classmethod` or `staticmethod` that doesn't require an instance for `self`:

   ```
   class Planning():
       @staticmethod  # Doesn't need self at all
       def foo(pop):
           print(pop.a)
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! That saved me, I was completely clueless! It makes perfect sense!

Comment: @dtkx: You're welcome. A heads up: Typically, `main` is a top-level function, not a method of a class. As written, `main` isn't even a real method (it doesn't take `self`, nor is it a `@staticmethod`, so attempting to call it on an instance of the class would fail); your code only works because it calls it on the class itself. I'd recommend dedenting `main` out of `Planning`, and invoking it as plain `main()` (not `Planning.main()`) to make it a bit more idiomatic. Sure, a `@staticmethod` would make it work (whether called on class or instance), but it's silly to make it part of the class.

Comment: Thank you so much again! Once again it makes total sense, as you could realize I am new to classes, I am still trying to figure out best practices, organization and trade offs between classes and functions. Your advice certainly helped a lot. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to instantiate `Planning` before calling methods on it:

```py
import copy
class FooInd():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class Planning():
    def foo(self, pop):
        print(pop.a)

    def main(self):
        ind = FooInd()
        self.foo(copy.deepcopy(ind))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Planning()
    p.main()
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Thaanks! Thats the direction I was missing!